# Setup PPTP to access home network transparently

Tags: macos, raspberry-pi, iptables, avahi, pptp

Setup PPTP to access home network transparently

I have **Raspberry Pi** box connected to home WiFi-router and running `pptpd`.  The local addresses is `192.168.1.32` (eth0) and `192.168.2.1` (ppp0) and local name `raspberry.local`.

I have **iMac** connected to the same router with local IP  `192.168.1.27` and local name `imac.local`

I have **Macbook** somewhere in the Internet connected to Raspberry’s PPTP with `192.168.2.10` on ppp0

[This picture](http://cl.ly/image/3G0x0x2H2n1K) shows more clearly.

### pptpd configuration

PPTP on Raspberry was installed  from [this simple script](https://github.com/viljoviitanen/setup-simple-pptp-vpn).

**/etc/pptpd.conf**

```
option /etc/ppp/options.pptpd
logwtmp
localip 192.168.2.1
remoteip 192.168.2.10-100
```

**/etc/ppp/options.pptpd**

```
name pptpd
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
require-mschap-v2
require-mppe-128
ms-dns 8.8.8.8
ms-dns 8.8.4.4
proxyarp
lock
nobsdcomp 
novj
novjccomp
nologfd
```

**/etc/rc.local**

```
…
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT  --protocol 47 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.2.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1356
…
```

### Curent connectivity

Macbook

- can connect to home PPTP and connect to Internet through the home router
- can connect to iMac and Raspberry via local IPs `192.168.1.27` and `192.168.1.32`
- can *NOT* resolve `raspberry.local` and `imac.local`

Raspberry

- can connect to iMac and Macbook via local IPs `192.168.1.27`  and `192.168.2.10`
- can resolve `imac.local`
- can *NOT* resolve `macbook.local`

iMac

- can connect to Raspberry via local IP `192.168.1.32`
- can resolve `raspberry.local`
- can *NOT* connect to Macbook via local IP `192.168.2.10` (**upd:** Solved by adding static route to the router)
- can *NOT* resolve `macbook.local`

### The goal

The goal is to connect and resolve local names from any to any. But I have no idea how to configure this: iptables, avahi, netatalk or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are 2 separate goals and you have to solve them separately.

For resolution to work: You need to set up a DNS server somewhere (iMac?) and designate it as a resolver in all your devices/computers. 
Or go with an easier setup, put the name <-> ip address relations into the /etc/hosts file on all your devices/computers

For connectivity: Your iMac simply "does not know" (i.e. no route) how to connect to what is behind the raspberry. However, it DOES work vice-verse since your raspberry is doing NAT for the macbook.

Do you have access to your WiFi router's routing table? If yes, you need to add a route to the PPP network (192.168.2.0/25) via raspberry's external IP address (192.168.1.32).

The exact command or configuration steps, however, depend on the vendor/model of your WiFi router, so I cannot give you a more detailed answer here.

Comment: Thanx! 
I've configured my router so now I can connect from my iMac to Macbook via IP (from 192.168.1.x to 192.168.2.x)

The second goal is about mDNS and Bonjour retranslation across the networks I think